# Doubt about a NE555

Tags: 555

I created this circuit a few days ago, but I'm a beginner in electronics, so I do not know if it's well done

This circuit causes the LED to turn on after 5 seconds and to keep it on

Could someone please tell me if it's okay, and if not, how could it be improved?

[image]

Comment: and did you try it?

Comment: If it works, why would you want to "improve" it?

Comment: I've only been able to test it in some simulators and it gives me an error

Comment: it's always good to know how to improve the circuit, in order to learn more about it

Comment: You need to ask the question much better?  Why do you have doubts?  What error did you get?  What simulator are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It looks basically okay. You should have 100nF or so across the Vcc to GND and from Vc (control voltage) to GND as bypass capacitors.

Also, show the polarity on your 100uF electrolytic capacitor.

You may get a significantly shorter than expected delay if you don't leave the power off for long enough. A resistor across the power can help with that, as can a Schottky diode  from the chip pins 6/2 to GND (reverse biased, of course).